# How to display teaser on taxonomy term page in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

I'm hitting a wall here. I have a block that lists my taxonomy terms and when I click to view that term page all I see is a list of node titles, the submitted by info, a comment link and RSS feed. There seems to be no way to add the teaser or remove some of the other items. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

[Theming fields and node](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxZQqgvJk3s). 
[API documentation about node variables](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.tpl.php).